# How to read an excel file present in SharePoint online document in C#, then I have to encrypt some columns and finally write it to Snowflake database?

Tags: c#, excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, azure-service-principal

I want to read an excel file present in SharePoint online document using service principals in C#. Then I want to encrypt some column values as they are sensitive and write them to the snowflake database.

**My main concern is how to read SharePoint online excel file using service principals which have access to that file in C#. I have gone through many blogs and some other StackOverflow questions but everyone is using a username and password to authenticate to SharePoint, I am willing to use service principals. And I think we can use service principals because in Azure Data Factory I am using them to get the file but not sure how to do it in C#.**

Some guidance will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved using Microsoft graph API:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sharepoint?view=graph-rest-1.0

We can authenticate using Client Credentials:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS

Thanks.